# Tiny PHP Script runs fine on dev server, fails on hosted server

Tags: php

Im pretty new to php, Ive got a linux server running php  5.5.9 , and all I want it to do is take whatever is sent to it in an http post, and dump it to a file.

Currently the code I have is this

```
<?php 
file_put_contents("outputfile.txt", file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

It works 100%, does exactly what I want when its on my own server.

When I upload it to my web server (HostGator) it gets a 500 error. The web server is running php 5.4, Im not sure if thats the issue.

Basically what Im trying to learn is why doesnt this work, and how do I fix it, its a pretty simple script.

Comment: Are there any errors? Is error reporting enable and configured? Did you check your php log?

Comment: Check error log like commented above but also check write permission on your folders. I know that some host (like hostpapa) will give you an 500 error if you have permission set to 0777.

Comment: @JohnCartwright Im not sure how to check if error reporting is enabled or configured. Im not even sure what kind of acsess I have to that type of stuff through a shared host like hostgator.

In the log I do get ""directory" is writeable by group" Ill try changing the permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John and Louis pointed me to the right answer, it was entirely the permissions on the folder the files were in. The folder was 777 for some reason, and switching it to 755 like the files were fixed it.

I had no idea that could even cause a 500 error

Comment: Since you are new, please don't forget to mark your answer if it is the resolution to your issue.

Comment: It says I cant accept my own answer for 2 days. Ive used other stack exchange sites, but now Im working a new job as the only programmer / IT employee so Ill probably be around a lot.